# ng-class within ng-repeat when object comes from other object/array

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

**[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/BApmfwaIU3XQSdLK9NSd?p=preview)**

I have an app that allows users to see info about live music and favorite the shows they like. Pushing the star button does this.  They can then see this information on their own music calendar page.

[image: stars]

I'm able to save and update the favoriting data into my database just fine now.  But I can't figure out how to style the star buttons (favoriting buttons) based on whether the user has favorited the item or not.  They should change color/style if they are favorited or not.

There is data that comes from the music shows and data about the user (their personal info or favorites).  These are separate bits of data.  So when I bring the shows info in via ng-repeat, this is different than the info I have on whether the user has favorited that show.

The jist of the question, then, is how to style items/icons using ng-class within an ng-repeat *when* the info on whether those items have been favorited (true or false) comes from another object or array (can create either).  Most of the examples with ng-repeat and ng-class are a alot simpler because the data on whether something is selected or not is within that same object.

**HTML**

```
  <div class="list-group">
    <div class="nav nav-stacked list-group-item" id="sidebar" ng-repeat=
    "show in shows[0]">
      <div>
        <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
          <h2>{{show.properties.price}}</h2>

          <p id="tagtext">{{show.properties.tags}}</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
          <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{show.properties.artist}}</h4>

          <p class="list-group-item-text">{{show.properties.venue}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="media col-md-3">
        <h2 class="fa fa-star-o" ng-click="toggleStarred(show)" ng-class="I don't know">
        </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The pertinent part of the html is around `<span class="pull-right star" ng-controller="StarredCtrl">`  That's what creates the star icon.

**Controller**

I'll include the plunker so as not to have to jam this up.

The object where the user favorites are stored looks like this

`$scope.loggedInUserFavorites = Object { $$conf: Object, $id: "favorites", $priority: null, show0: true, show1: false, show3: true, show5: false }`

using Angular.foreach I pared it down to this:

`Object { 0: false, 1: false, 3: true, 5: false }`

How can I access those true/false properties of `$scope.loggedInUserFavorites` on my template to style the star icon?

**[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/BApmfwaIU3XQSdLK9NSd?p=preview)**

Comment: inside ng-repeat, you can find the index of the item with the attribute $index. Tie this to a method to grab the specific show and see if the user has starred it? if they have, use a different ng-class for displaying the star

Comment: @sanghas26 So ng-class should call a function with $index?  And then that function with see if the item is starred or not?

Comment: How do I access or return a CSS class from inside a controller?

Answer (score 2):

Actually this should work:

`<h2 class="fa fa-star-o" ng-click="toggleStarred(show)" ng-class="{fillgreen:loggedInUserFavorites[show.properties.id]}">`

As scopes prototypically inherit from their parents, you do actually have access to both the show model from the ng-repeat scope, and loggedInUserFavorites from the StarredCtrl scope.

Cheers!

Comment: Really appreciate you answering.  I've tried this and versions of it but no dice so far.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (where shows[$index].starred is your logic to check if the show has been favorited)

```
<div class="media col-md-3">
    <h2 class="fa fa-star-o" ng-click="toggleStarred(show)" ng-class="{starred: shows[$index].starred, no-star: !shows[$index].starred}">
    </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Wondering if something is loading too soon/late for this logic to apply.  Stumped on this.

Answer (score 0):

I basically used both @sanghas26 and @HeberLZ's to come up with:

`<h2 class="fa" ng-click="toggleStarred(show)" ng-class="{'fa-star': loggedInUserFavorites[show.properties.id], 'fa-star-o': !loggedInUserFavorites[show.properties.id]}"></h2>`

So I changed the `h2` to `fa` and then used the full and empty stars as the css classes.  I really don't know why `fillgreen` and `fillblue` didn't work here.  Will continue to investigate.

Anyway, it works.  This took 6 weeks to figure out.

Comment: Maybe this would work even better?: <h2 ng-click="toggleStarred(show)" ng-class="{fa: true, 'fa-star': loggedInUserFavorites[show.properties.id], 'fa-star-o': !loggedInUserFavorites[show.properties.id]}"></h2>